# How do I stop flex images from overlapping each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I've created an admin page using PouchDB/JS to upload content to a database so it will display on another page, but when the items are uploaded to the main page they overlap each other when the page is resized, and/or do not fall into another column despite

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

being used in the container. My JS creates new entries on the main page so the code  isn't exactly the same, but I've created some divs with the same image to demonstrate the problem. It looks fine when on a webpage, but this is what happens when the page is resized:

[image: problem]

This is similar to what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: desired layout]

I want all of the images to be a fixed size (one third of the container) (even if the image uploaded has different dimensions), and when the page is made smaller I want the boxes to fall below each other (so only 1 image per column on mobile devices)

Could someone take a look at my code and let me know how to solve my problem please?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', georgia, arial;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-align: left;
}

.sortFilms {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff6699;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #aaaaaa;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.filmRow img {
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.filmRow {
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#filmContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sorting {
  width: 20%;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  color: #AAAAAA;
}

#formTitle {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="img/rv-logo.png">
  <p class="tagline">Want to know whether or not it's worth paying to watch a certain film or not? See what we think first!</p>
</header>

<div class="sortFilms">
  <h2 id="formTitle">Browse reviews</h2>
  <p class="sorting"> Sort by:
    <label>Ascending <input type="radio" name="sort" checked/></label>
    <label>Descending <input type="radio" name="sort"/></label>
  </p>
  <div id='filmContainer'>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/)?

Comment: @Mukyuu why bootstrap? this can be done without bootstrap and if not needed it only increase size of page

Comment: Well, for sure it could. I'm just giving one of many possibility.

Comment: here you go sir `.filmRow img {width:100%;border-radius: 20px;}`

Comment: @Mukyuu I've neverused bootstrap before, I'm actually really new to coding so this is all a bit of a mind boggle

Comment: @NullPoiиteя unfortunately I'm still getting the same result, the images are just bigger now :(

Comment: @zee run code snippet in my answer and it looks ok to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw you applied padding to flex child.

The solution is simple. Apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.filmRow` .

The reason is that you set `.filmRow`'s `width: 33%` while adding padding to it.

`box-sizing: border-box;` is making the whole `div` including padding to be `width: 33%`.

https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/ZwzOXa

**EDIT:**

And since the `width` is being set to 33% of the parent. Without a `min-width` , flex child will not wrap because 33% is always a relative unit.

Comment: Okay so you've solved why only 2 boxes would appear at a time, but the issue on resize is still there. How would I go about making the third box (for example) drop to the row below when the page is resized?

Comment: border-box with `.filmRow img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}` will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

try remove min-width from `.filmRow img`

```
.filmRow {
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.filmRow img {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

---

Working demo

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', georgia, arial;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-align: left;
}

.sortFilms {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff6699;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #aaaaaa;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

 .filmRow {
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.filmRow img {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#filmContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sorting {
  width: 20%;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  color: #AAAAAA;
}

#formTitle {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="img/rv-logo.png">
  <p class="tagline">Want to know whether or not it's worth paying to watch a certain film or not? See what we think first!</p>
</header>

<div class="sortFilms">
  <h2 id="formTitle">Browse reviews</h2>
  <p class="sorting"> Sort by:
    <label>Ascending <input type="radio" name="sort" checked/></label>
    <label>Descending <input type="radio" name="sort"/></label>
  </p>
  <div id='filmContainer'>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="filmRow"><img src="https://www.arthipo.com/image/cache/catalog/genel-tasarim/all-posters/sinema-cinema-film-postersleri/yabanci-filmler/pfilm311-deadpool_2d2fe71a-movie-film-poster-sales-poster-baski-1000x1000.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem here is the images resize with the page, and not fall into the row below. I want the boxes to be a fixed size :(

Comment: @Zee lets discuss here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign

Comment: I'll check the link out now